# How to disable media gallery permission of Hill Climb Racing 2?

Tags: permissions

I have installed Hill Climb Racing 2. It asked for access to my gallery. For installation I permitted it. But now I want to disable it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy to do so. All you need to do is to change your App Permissions. All you need to do is the following:
1. Goto Settings of your mobile phone
2. Find the option Apps
3. Scroll down the list to find out Hill Climb Racing 2
4. Look for Permission Tab
5. Search the list of permissions for the permission you want to disable
6. Click it and disable it

For more information and detailed overview, I recommend you to see this video for further details:

[How to Manage App Permissions on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAqB2TgQlls)

Comment: Amazing. I got it done easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to disable app permissions is to use a tiny but powerful utility. This utility is known as Lucky Patcher. However, you will not be able to find it from Play Store. [Download Lucky Patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download-latest/). Follow some simple steps to install it and use it to manage app permissions.

Comment: It is best if you mention how to use that app within the answer because link-only answers lose their usefulness once the link expires.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the website freeluckypatcher.com? Our policy on promotion requires full disclosure of affiliation in all such posts where the affiliated product/link is mentioned.

Comment: @Firelord Not to mention the website isn't the official one.